# Why are my soft body objects doing this?[Blender 2.8]

Tags: physics

so basiccally, I want to recreate some things I made in v2.79 and can't. Now when I attempt soft body physics they always end up like this.
[image]

Here's the blend file if you need it:
[image]

The image and file are following a tutorial on this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LeO5eOunzeQ&t=85s and I did everything from scratch the same as them.

Either the default settings are different for whatever reason, or blender 2.8 has changed something I don't understand.

Comment: @Yash User's file shouldn't be uploaded to Blendexchange without their permission. See: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2277/241

Comment: @RayMairlot Okayy!

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm experiencing the same issue :(

Comment: @d2kagw unfortunately no, I no longer need it but will leave it here hoping someone posts an answer to help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Add SubSurf(Subdivision Surface) Modifier to your UV Sphere:
And increase the values of Render and Viewport. Also, make sure they are same or you'll get different results in the render.

[image]